# filtering with Underscore

Tags: underscore.js

I have the following underscore code which pulls out data from an external JSON and displays it in a list.

```
     <script type="text/template" class="template">
        <ul>
                <% _.each( rc , function(productTile) {
                      if(_.findWhere(ids,productTile.id){
 %>
                <li class="productTile" data-id="<%= productTile.id %>">
                <img src="<%= productTile.images[0] %>" alt=""/>
            <h3>Demo<%= productTile["name"] %></h3>
            <p><%= productTile.price.formatted %></p>

                </li>           
                <% }  }); %>
      </script>
    var listingTemplate = _.template(
               $( "script.template" ).html()
           );
```

In the external JSON file there are around 30 products, but I would like to only show information for 6 specific products, which I declare in this internal JSON:

```
 var templateData = {
            "ultimate": [
                    {
            "id": "50236775",
                    "id": "50237067",
                    "id": "50236776",
                    "id": "50236777",
                    "id": "50236778"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I'm using `if(_.findWhere(ids,productTile.id){` but it's not working, is there something wrong with the way that is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is your internal JSON is incorrect, you can't have same keys `id` in an object. You should rather just create an array of `ids`:

```
var ids = ["50236775","50237067","50236776","50236777","50236778"];
```

Add a check in template :

```
<script type="text/template" class="template">
<ul>
    <% _.each( rc , function(productTile) {
        //ids is external array passed to template
        if(_.contains(ids, productTile.id)){
    %>
            <li class="productTile" data-id="<%= productTile.id %>">
                <img src="<%= productTile.images[0] %>" alt=""/>
            <h3>Demo<%= productTile["name"] %></h3>
            <p><%= productTile.price.formatted %></p>
        </li>           
    <% 
        }
     }); 
    %>
</ul>   
</script>
```

Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/underscore-template-editor/launch) to play with underscore templates.

**Another approach** :

Before you pass `rc` to template filter the products:

```
var rc = _.filter(rc, function(productTile){
   return _.contains(ids, productTile.id);
});
```

In this case you don't have to update your template.

Comment: Hi, thanks that contains filter isn't working for some reason :(

Comment: wouldn't findwhere be better?

Comment: Make sure `ids` and `productTile.id` are both either `string` or `number`. If their data type is different it won't work. Try `_.contains(ids, productTile.id+"")`, if `ids` is an array of strings.

Comment: your missing a bracket here: if(_.contains(ids, productTile.id)){ please amend, because that answer is right